# How to place a WebBrowser control below other controls?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I tried setting the Canvas.ZIndex property, but when I scroll, the HTML in the webBrowser control still floats above the menu bar in the Silverlight navigation application.

You can see the sample code below:

I just created an empty Silverlight Navigation Application and added the following in Home.XAML:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="Test.Home" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
    Title="Home"
    Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}" Canvas.ZIndex="1">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource PageScrollViewerStyle}">

            <StackPanel x:Name="ContentStackPanel">

                <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" 
                                   Text="Home Content"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblInstructions" Style="{StaticResource ContentTextStyle}" 
                                   Text="Instructions "/>
                <WebBrowser Name="HTMLContent" Height="850" Width="600" Canvas.ZIndex="0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblScribble" Style="{StaticResource ContentTextStyle}" 
                                   Text="Scribble here "/>
                <InkPresenter Name="inkPresenter1" DataContext="{Binding}" Cursor="Stylus" Opacity="1" />
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

And then set the HTML content in the code behind:

```
HTMLContent.NavigateToString("<p>Some HTML</p>");
```

When I scroll down, the HTML content goes above the navigation at the top. That tells me the webBrowser control is above the rest of the controls. But setting the Canvas.ZIndex isn't doing anything.

Comment: Need. More. Information. At least post your XAML, don't make people guess.

Comment: @slugster Sorry I thought the question was very straightforward. I'll post the XAMl now.

Comment: SL5 update... same story with in browser elevated trust WebBrowser control :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common "[airspace issue](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/06/22/silverlight-html-and-the-webbrowser-control-for-offline-apps.aspx)", which is similar to the [WPF airspace issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There isn't currently a way to make it appear behind your other Silverlight content.

(For the first link search for "airspace" to find the related info).

Comment: @[CodeNaked] Thanks for answering. Shame it isn't possible, though :(

Comment: This just totally rained on my SL5 InBrowser-WebBrowser parade.  I have a menu that drops down BEHIND the web browser control in my content.  Telerik has a "RadHtmlPlaceholder" control that can display HTML content but requires Windowless mode :(