# Either Free or Paid alternative to Silverlight Web Browser Control to target visibility(z-index) problems?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, webbrowser-control

I am using Silverlight WebBrowser Control in one of my application, and all the Silverlight Content hides behind the WebBrowser Control.

I know, we can't do anything about it and have read about the Air Space Issue also. I have also gone through the following links:-

[How to place a WebBrowser control below other controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492220/how-to-place-a-webbrowser-control-below-other-controls)

But its really required to solve it for my application, so I am looking for some alternatives, either FREE or can be PAID too.

I have read about the FireFox Gecko browser, but it seems it is a pure Windows Forms Control and I wonder whether I can use it in Silverlight or not, and also whether it will solve the z-index issues if we can at all use it in silverlight.

Does any body has any solution for this ? Either Free or Paid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesomium is a fairly decent browser since it uses chrome as it's base and it's a native control for WPF so it'll respect your z-index. However, it's a wpf control right now and it's not clear if SL is easily supported or not, but this may help.

Awesomium website: http://awesomium.com/

some mention on how to get a silverlight dll to use:
http://support.awesomium.com/discussions/questions/119-using-awesomium-with-silverlight-40